# Multi warehouses inventory stock database design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, inventory, stock

What is the right database structure for an Inventory Database that stores Items as below:

1-Items comes along with Purchase Order

2-All items in PO goes to the General warehouse for stock take

3-Quality Department checks the Items

4-Items that passed quality check goes to Inventory and affect items quantity

5-Items that did not pass quality goes to Quarantine area

Thanks.

Comment: The right database structure is the one that allows you to perform steps 1 - 5.  Show some work.

Comment: With what you posted there are far more questions than answers. Nearly everything there all depend on requirements of the system and business rules. You seem to need some help but you forgot to post a complete question.

Comment: The WROX book on Database Design is excellent.